# Auto increment for transaction number (Eclipse Java)

Tags: java, increment, auto-increment

I want to get increasing value starting with 1 so that I get TK-1 all the way to TK-n.

What I've tried is:

```
public class Main {
addTicket();


public void addTicket() {
int a;
String ticket;
a = getA();
ticket = "TK-"+ a
System.out.println(ticket)
}

public int getA() {
    int a, b;
    a = 0;
    b = a++;
    return a;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main();

}
}
```

Sorry it's my first time learning to code, can someone explain to me why it isn't working and what should I do to make it work ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be good if you explained what you see as 'not working' here, and what you've done to try and figure it out. For example, you've not introduced any kind of loop, so there's no way this is going to do anything more than once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need an autoincrease ID, you need a static int:

```
public class Ticket {
    static int ticketID = 1;


    public void addTicket() {
        int a;
        String ticket;
        a = getticketID();
        ticket = "TK-" + a;
        System.out.println(ticket);
    }
    public int getticketID () {
        return ticketID++;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ticket test  = new Ticket();
        test.addTicket();
        test.addTicket();
        test.addTicket();

    }
}
```

output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juk9S.png)